# How can I detect Bash >=4.0?

Tags: bash, version

I am writing a script that uses `read -i`, so it requires Bash 4.0 or newer.

Unfortunately, as of early 2020, macOS still ships with Bash 3.x, and many users of my script will be using Macs. Since Apple has changed the default shell to zsh, I have no hope that they'll update the bundled version.

As such, I want my script to detect whether Bash is new enough and exit with a helpful error message that directs the user to upgrade.

I know I can compare `${BASH_VERSION}`, but that's a string with a non-numeric, potentially unreliable format. It feels fragile to make assumptions about it.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

```
requireBash4() {
  if <something here>; then
    >&2 echo "Bash 4.0 or newer is required."
    >&2 echo "Once you're upgraded, re-run this script."
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Comment: Bash 5 says `5.0.16(1)-release`, Bash 4 says `4.3.46(1)-release`. These are examples of course but can't you just compare the first number with 4?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/916978

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk that's exactly the sort of fragile assumptions I'm trying to avoid. What happens when Bash reaches version 10?

Comment: Nothing, you still extract first number. That's simple with `cut`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, which is exactly the problem: you're mis-detecting Bash 10 (which is compatible) as Bash 1 (which isn't).

Comment: @Mark: `echo '1.3.46(1)-release' | cut -d . -f 1` will print 1, `echo '10.3.46(1)-release' | cut -d . -f 1` will print 10.

Comment: And what happens when they change the format of the string? @mosvy's answer is what I was looking for. Structured data, no fragile string parsing.

Comment: @JakeRobb: such questions can be asked endlessly. What if they deprecate `BASH_VERSINFO`? What if they rename `BASH_VERSINFO` to something else? What if they change meaning of `BASH_VERSINFO[0]`? And so on.

Comment: You don't really have to do anything, other than *document* that your script requires `bash` 4 or later. It's the *user* who is responsible for making sure they have a compliant version to run your script.

Comment: FWIW, even with `BASH_VERSION`, you don't need `cut`. You could use `[ "${BASH_VERSION%%.*}0" -ge 40 ]` (or ok, `-lt 40` ;-)), but I don't see the point of such contorsions.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I find those what-ifs (changing the nature of something that’s clearly intended to be interpreted programmatically) to be FAR less likely than mine (changing a string that is clearly NOT intended for parsing). I’m trying to make a best effort here, and your suggestions are clearly within the realm of things I said I wasn’t looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if ((BASH_VERSINFO >= 4)); then ...
```

Notice that `BASH_VERSINFO` is an array. As with any array in bash, using it as a plain variable refers to its 0-th element. You can also use `((BASH_VERSINFO[0] >= 4))` if you find it more clear.

And yes, this variable and syntax are supported since at least bash 2.0.

> `BASH_VERSINFO`
>
> A readonly array variable whose members hold version information
>                 for this instance of bash.  The values  assigned  to  the  array
>                 members are as follows:
>
> `BASH_VERSINFO[0]`        The major version number (the release).
>   `BASH_VERSINFO[1]`        The minor version number (the version).
>   `BASH_VERSINFO[2]`        The patch level.
>   `BASH_VERSINFO[3]`        The build version.
>   `BASH_VERSINFO[4]`        The release status (e.g., beta1).
>   `BASH_VERSINFO[5]`        The value of `MACHTYPE`.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: probably clearer to just write the index explicitly: `((BASH_VERSINFO[0] >= 4))`

Comment: Also, given the sample code in the question, it should be `< 4`, not `>= 4`. :)